# How to write output to a file of the same name as the input?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I am wondering how to to process files from some folder dir1 if they are piped through various tasks and in the end I'd like the output to be written in the same folder structure and file names, i.e. say I have 2 files; `dir1/file1` and `dir1/file2`. I want the following command:

```
task1 dir1/* | task2 | task3 --output dir2/${filename}
```

to output `dir2/file1` and `dir2/file2` which should represent the processed files.

Answer (score 5):

Loop over the files in `dir1`, get the basename of each file, process it, write to output file:

```
for path in dir1/*; do
    name="${path##*/}"
    task1 "$path" | task2 | task3 --output "dir2/$name"
done
```

The variable substitution `${path##*/}` will take the value of the `path` variable and remove everything up to (and including) the last `/`.  This produces the basename of the file.

`task1` is then performed on the file in `dir1`, the result is passed on to `task2` and the output of that is given to `task3`.  The last task uses `dir2/$name` as the operand for its `--output` switch, where `$name` is the filename without path from the `$path` valiable.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd "dir1" && \
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c '
   # task2 on "$1" | task3  > "/path/to/dir2/${1##*/}
' {} {} \;
```

Comment: Bit overcomplicated perhaps, and what happened to `task1`?